# How to fix/changeposition camera in ros3djs

Tags: ros, ros3djs, rosbridge, ros-kinetic, roslib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

So I have this PointCloud2 messages which are generated from a drone camera and I am trying to render them on the browser using ros3djs. the cloud of points appear in my viewer but I couldn't change the camera initial position using `cameraPosition :`  when initializing the options of the ROS3D.Viewer Object. A second problem is that the scene auto moves/rotates when the camera of the drone moves. I tried changing the `Viewer.cameraControls.autoRotate`  to false to fix the camera view but nothing changes. I am using ros-Kinetic. How can I fix that?

Thank you in advance !!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332170/how-to-fix/changeposition-camera-in-ros3djs/) by [WhatWhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/45056/whatwhat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So after some work. I figured out that for, the PointCloud2, the camera is not moving at all but the points are rotating. And ros3djs do not have something already implemented to ignore rotation. And for the `cameraPostion:` issue, after reading the code of ros3djs I noticed that the documentation is wrong so instead of `cameraPostion:` write `cameraPose:` to change the camera position in the scene.

---

Originally posted by [WhatWhat](https://answers.ros.org/users/45056/whatwhat/) with karma: 16 on 2019-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0